# Run Phonegap application, that supports HTML5 and Javascript on Android Wear

Tags: eclipse, html, android-emulator, apk, wear-os

I had already executed Hello World apk on Android wear emulator, now I want to use HTML inside asset folder to execute it in wear emulator but I am not getting any success

Comment: I think you might want to state your question more precisely. What exactly is it you're trying, what kind of error message do you get, etc.

Comment: I want to use phonegap in android wear, is it possible, i tried but the app gets stopped by emulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android wear supports only Java application not to render HTML document. Please refer to https://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html for Android were app in details.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work like you are used to from normal Phonegap/Cordova yet. But as you can use a full Chrome Browser on the watch (like com.appfour.wearbrowser) I think it can be done!
So what you need to do is fork Chrome on Android Wear and let it launch your website...

Answer (score 1):

For simple HTML, our Android HTML software renderer should work, see https://github.com/kobjects/htmlview