# How to build Phonegap Build application for Android Wear?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, wear-os

I would like to build a pure HTML5 and Javascript based Phonegap application, that can be build with Phonegap Build and be able to deploy it to Android Wear.

**If this is possible at this moment, then what steps should be taken?**

My research so far:

1. There is [a notice on Phonegap Build forum](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/can-i-create-an-phonegap-app-with-an-android-wear-module) about [Ball Escape game](http://phonegap.com/app/ball-escape-android-wear/), that is reported to be built with Phonegap and ready to be run on Android Wear. But, there are no details on how this was done except a meaningless comment by Phonegap Build rep Amir, that *someone did this*.
2. I went through [Building Apps for Wearables](https://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html), but found nothing on this matter so far.
3. Questions like https://stackoverflow.com/q/29834268/1469208 or [Run Phonegap application, that supports HTML5 and Javascript on Android Wear](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24635244/1469208) brings no actual answer  to my question. Second one even seems to be against, as given answers claims, that it is not possible to build HTML5 based application for Android Wear as it supports only Java based native apps. But, then again, there is [Ball Escape game](http://phonegap.com/app/ball-escape-android-wear/), whos author claims, that it was done in Phonegap.

I [know](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1LD8YPrqeMs), that I can use [CocoonJS from Ludei](https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/) to build HTML5 based application for many platforms, *including* Android Wear, pretty much like I do this in Phonegap (Ludei also offers cloud-based build of their apps and it even seems free). But, I have some doubts about performance for my simple data transfer application, because CocoonJS seems to be optimized for high-performance games instead.  Plus, I'd like to avoid switching Phonegap to another environment, if that would be possible.

Comment: Kindly have a look at this.

https://github.com/tgardner/cordova-androidwear/

Comment: https://github.com/tgardner/cordova-androidwear-example

Comment: Don't those assume you've already built an androidwear app natively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@trejder,
at the moment, you have it correct. There is very little support for AndroidWear, but that is not to say that it is not possible. Most Phonegap Apps depend on Java (or the Equivalent on platforms other than Android) to do the heavy lifting. If you are seeing some tools, it is likely you will see more.

One alternative is to team up with a Java author to write the most basic portions you need, but I have found little luck in this.

However, given all this, I would not fret. Over the last two years many of the wearables (I've seen) in the wild are using BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy). If this is so, for the wearables you are look at, then you are in luck.

*Bluetooth Developer Forum*
https://developer.bluetooth.org/Community/Pages/default.aspx

*Leading Bluetooth Developer tools for Linux*
http://www.bluez.org/

Best of Luck,
Jesse

Answer (score 0):

Ball Escape game was made with CocoonJS and Unity. Actually CocoonJS is unavailable. I didn't find any alternative to make HTML 5 apps for Wear os with PhoneGap or Cordova so far.