# Does android Hybrid application(Cordova based) works in android wearables?

Tags: android, cordova, native, hybrid, android-wear-data-api

Does an android hybrid application(Cordova based) work in android wearable? Otherwise, would I need to develop mobile application in native and sync it with android wearable?

Comment: which type of application ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that, but you can communicate with your android wear with this [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-androidwear).

[Here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/support/index.html) is list of all supported platforms.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, currently there is very little support for AndroidWear in cordova. you may have to check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500875/how-to-build-phonegap-build-application-for-android-wear) which can be helpful for you.